# Handling unwanted request method

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman

In my post controller js file I have the following code for creating a new post. Within it I have a code that checks to see if the method equals "POST" just in case if in postman I select "GET" for a "POST" route it should display a custom error message. However, I keep getting a 404 error.

The following code is in the post.controller.js file:

```
const {
  createPost,
  getPosts
} = require("./post.service");

module.exports = {

  //Controller for creating new post
  createPost: (req, res) =>{
    if(req.method !== 'POST'){
      return res.status(400).json({
          message: 'Error. Incorrect method.'
     });
    }
    const body = req.body;
    createPost(body, (err, results) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success:0,
          message:"Error. Unable to create post"
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        message: "Post was successfully created",
        data: results

      });
    });

  }
}
```

The following code is from the post.router.js file:

```
const {
  createPost,
  getPosts
} = require("./post.controller");
const router = require("express").Router();


router.post("/createPost", createPost);
router.get("/getPosts", getPosts);



module.exports = router;
```

Instead, I am getting a 404 error in postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/posts/createPost</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your routes file in order to have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: Thanks Luis. I just updated my post with the router file

Comment: Where is your getPosts controller defined?

Comment: Both createPost and getPosts are within the post.controller.js file within module.exports I just didnt post it on here

Comment: So basically what I am trying to do is if I accidentally select "GET" method in postman for a route that is meant to be for a "POST" method then I want to display a custom error message instead of the 404 error which I just posted on here

Comment: Try not deleting answered questions because they might be useful for people with your same problem or aim

Comment: Hey Luis my code is a school project so I am not sure if it is safe for me to have a portion of my code online if I have figured out the issue. What do you think?

Comment: Sooner or later people come up with the same question and therefore someone answers. The aim of the answer is precisely to help everyone that at some point has the same problem (that's what this site is about). Don't worry about people finding the result as the aim of school is for you to learn and as I see you are in the good path ;) Mark my answer as correct if it's what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that you are trying to GET a route that has not been handled in your app. In this case `router.get('/createPost', yourController)` is missing.

Please note that this approach you are trying is not recommended and not a good practice. Try to define each route and method for it's own purpose instead.

If you are still interested in achieving this you could try to add the missing route like this:

`router.get('/createPost', (req, res)=>{res.send(YOUR_ERROR)});`